# Hiding java package structure in url

Tags: java, servlets

Our current web application url reveals the class package structure to the end user. This is because in web.xml the servlet mapping tag is as follows

Servlet_ name
/servlet/com.xxx.yyy.ClassName

Is there any way by which i can hide the package structure. i.e com.xxx.yyy.ClassName to just ClassName?

Thanks
Sameer

Comment: Not a Java person, but perhaps some sort of lookup table?  MySupaLib = com.lib.my.Supa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is recognizeable as an [old and vulrenable feature](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q3) of Tomcat's builtin [`InvokerServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/InvokerServlet.html). To fix this, disable it  in Tomcat's `/conf.web.xml` by removing or outcommenting the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` entries associated with `<servlet-name>invoker</servlet-name>`.

This was a security hole in the ancient Tomcat versions and was fixed in Tomcat 5 and upwards where it is been deprecated and by default disabled. It will be removed in Tomcat 7.

You need to explicitly define all of the servlets in webapp's `web.xml` yourself along with a decent `url-pattern`. If you have pretty a lot of servlets, consider the *Front Controller Pattern*, i.e. just only one servlet which delegates and executes the desired business logic based on under each the request method, request URI, request pathinfo and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Fix your web.xml url mappings.

If for some bizarre reason this isn't possible you could add this filter in front to rewrite the urls:

http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/